# How can I pass username in controller?

Tags: laravel, mongodb, session, controller

Username is store in my session. I am working on leave management module.
My Leave module's table has these fields 
User Name, Leave Type, Duration, Status, & Action.
Apart from username all details I can insert and list in list view.
But my user name is store in session. 
How can i get it from session and store in database In Username field??

Code in my view file

```
@if(Session::has('key'))
    <?php $username = Session::get('key')['username']; ?>
@endif

    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $username ?>">
```

Code In My controller file

```
 public function leaveApplication(Request $request)
    {
        $leave = new LeaveManagement();

        $leave->username = $request->get('username');
        $leave->leaveType = $request->get('leaveType');
        $leave->startDate = $request->get('startDate');
        $leave->endDate = $request->get('endDate');
        $leave->fromLeave = $request->get('fromLeave');
        $leave->fromHalfDayLeaveType = $request->get('fromHalfDayLeaveType');
        $leave->toLeave = $request->get('toLeave');
        $leave->toHalfDayLeaveType = $request->get('toHalfDayLeaveType');
        $leave->fullDayLeave = $request->get('fullDayLeave');
        $leave->typeOfLeave = $request->get('typeOfLeave');
        $leave->reasonForLeave =$request->get('reasonForLeave');
        $leave->status = 'Pending';

        $leave->save();

        return redirect('leave');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Laravel global session helper: `session(keyName)`. 
To get username from session and store it in database:

```
$username = session('username');

$leave = new Leave();
$leave->username = $username;
$leave->save();
```

For more information on Laravel session see [Laravel Session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session)

Comment: Not working..
What should i write in my blade file??

Comment: You can pass username variable like return view('view.name', ['username' => $username]). Then in blade you can use {{ $username }} variable.

Answer (score 0):

After login, Auth maintains user table fields in it. You can access it like that -

```
echo Auth::user()->name or echo Auth::user()->email
```

It will return the expected values as : "usersname" and "useremail@domain.com".

If you are not using Auth, then you can get username from your session and save it in DB like that -

```
$user = session()->get('user')
$username = $user->username;

$leave = new LeaveManagement();
$leave->username = $username;
$leave->save();
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I am not using Auth, wait I'll put code in question

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: I got this error
Trying to get property 'username' of non-object

Answer (score 0):

you can get object from your session and access to its attributes.some thing like:

```
$user = session()->get('user')
$username = $user->username
```

or after logging you can access your user's username with:

```
auth()->user()->username
```